# how to create google like dropdown search box using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap, and would like to create a dropdown on a search box. I am trying to emulate gmail's search bar, where the input search box has a caret at the end, which can be clicked to open a form.

I am trying to use bootstrap's dropdown to show a div, when the caret is clicked. However I am  not able to place the caret inside the input box like google does.

Looking at google's code I see that they have an input box without border placed alongside of a dropdown caret, embedded in a div with a border.

I am not able to override the border property of the bootstrap input box. Has anyone tried it ?

Below is my code -

```
<div class="input-append dropdown">

  <input type="text" name="puesto" class="input-xlarge noBorder"   placeholder="Email Address"/>    <a class="dropdown-toggle btn" id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
    <b class="caret"></b>   </a>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">    Hello world   </ul>   <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="icon-filter"></i></button> </div> 

<style type="text/css">   .noBorder {border-top-width: 0px;} </style>
```

Comment: you open to add jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a class to help overriding, like:

```
<input class="the-input" type="text" />
```

And then get rido of that border:

```
input.the-input {
    border: none transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
    filter:-;    /* for IE */
}
```